# Applications of $\infty$-categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, big-list, higher-category-theory

I am learning some basics of $\infty$-category theory, and am looking for articles that use the theory of $\infty$-categories to do cool things. Do you know of any articles that are relatively readable, whatever that means, that one could read to get more familiar with the theory in practice?

I was imagining getting a nice list going of papers in a range of topics, so I would like to leave the actual subject of the paper rather open ended. That way, I, or other potentially interested parties could find a paper that fit their interests.

Note that I am not looking for articles on the foundations of $\infty$-category theory, but rather articles that utilize the theory; I want to see it in action.